# How do i make a card hover and rotate on top of a stand?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am attempting a nft project for collectible cards. Regardless if they sell it is a learning experience for me as a new blender user.

I have completed my card and stand but now I want to animate it a little to give it more flare. To start I have no idea how to animate an object in blender yet as I am still very new. I have tried looking for tutorials but none quite show what I want to do.

My question to you all is how do I rig or animate my scene so that my card rotates a few degrees left and right (not a full 360, more like 5 degrees each way).

To edit my question, let me just say that I am so new to blender and the animation process that I don't know where to go.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi :). I'm no animator, but this should be very simple even without any rigging. Just animating the object rotation should do.

Comment: Fair enough I agree it should be simple, I have edited my post question to be a little more specific about my problem.

Comment: in that case I recommend to visit some tutorial that covers **Blender animation with keyframes basics** you just want to use rotation and maybe location keyframe as well at one frame 1, go to keyframe 10, rotate it by 5°, add rotation keyframe and repeat

Comment: the problem with your question now is, that you don't focus on ONE question as you should (these are the rules, i didn't make them). So you ask for rotation animation of card, and additionally for a text animation  and so on. So i think your question will be closed unless you ask one question. I agree with MikoCG...and i will answer just one question of your multiple questions

Answer (score 0):

So here i answer the question, how can i rotate a text around a stand?

Add a text -> shift A -> Text

Tab -> edit your text as you want

[image]

R X 90

R Z 90

G X 5

Shift A -> Empty -> Sphere

[image]

Now select your text in object mode, then shift-select the sphere

[image]

CTRL-P -> Object

Select the Empty

Hover cursor over z-location and press I

[image]

[image]

go to frame 100

[image]

enter 360 in z location

[image]

Hover over z location and press I again

[image]

When the cursor is in 3D Viewport, press space and watch:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and sorry about multiple questions, I will try this as soon as I get home. Thanks for your help